# Store hexadecimal numbers in a list python

Tags: python, list, syntax

I want to store hexadecimal numbers in a list. Doing this in python gives the following error:
`a = [2a, cd, 12, 11, bd, 26, 64, 11, 2d, 34, 12, 55, 63, 67, e8]`

```
File "main.py", line 4
    a = [2a, cd, 12, 11, bd, 26, 64, 11, 2d, 34, 12, 55, 63, 67, e8]
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Prefix the hex constants with `0x`, e.g. `0x2a`.  Otherwise how could it know they're hex?  Especially things like `12`, which are valid decimal constants.  `0x12` and `12` have very different values.

Comment: You may try to - print([0x2a])   Reminder - Python hex numbers starting with `0x`